# Append sub dictionary to main dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a function that collects dictionary values to subdict, how do I append this to my main dictionary as a nested entry?

```
Dict = {}
def getDetail():
    subdict = {}
    first_name = input("Enter first name")
    if first_name.lower() == 'quit':
        return None
    else:
        last_name = input("Enter last name")
        nick_name = input("Enter nickname")
        address = input("Enter address")
        number = input("Enter phone number")
        subdict['nick'] = nick_name 
        subdict['firstname'] = first_name
        subdict['lastname'] = last_name
        subdict['address'] = address
        subdict['number'] = number
        return subdict
```

I want the result to return a nested entry, indexed by `['nick']` so Dict looks like this

`{'Johnny': {'firstname': 'John', 'lastname': 'Johnson', 'address': '103 Alpine Drive', 'nick':'Johnny', 'number': '021-233-4555'}}`

Comment: `Dict['subdict'] = getDetail()`?

Comment: Could you clarify what you want the result to look like?  Are you trying to build a dict of directory entries where the key is a name (like a phone book)?  Do you just want  Dict to be a list of subdicts?  Or is it what Will suggested above?

Comment: I want the subdict entries to be nested dictionaries indexed by nickname inside Dict like  this: `{'Johnny': {'firstname': 'John', 'lastname': 'Johnson', 'address': '103 Alpine Drive', 'nick':'Johnny', 'number': '021-233-4555'}`

Comment: and that is the case was Will told you. I'll add you one other sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you could:

```
Dict = {}
def getDetail():
    subdict = {}
    first_name = input("Enter first name")
    if first_name.lower() != 'quit':
        last_name = input("Enter last name")
        nick_name = input("Enter nickname")
        address = input("Enter address")
        number = input("Enter phone number")
        subdict['nick'] = nick_name 
        subdict['firstname'] = first_name
        subdict['lastname'] = last_name
        subdict['address'] = address
        subdict['number'] = number
        dict[nick_name] = subdict
```

Comment: Hey, AJP - glad it helped.  (You might also officially accept an answer if it provided what you needed.)

Answer (score 1):

You can just do so as you would normally do for any entry.

```
my_dict[key] = value
```

Following this format:

```
my_dict = Dict
value = getDetail()
key = "Up to you"
my_dict[key] = value
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively written, simple and dirty:

```
MyDict = {}
def GetDetail():    
    first_name = raw_input("Enter first name: ")
    if first_name.lower() == 'quit':
        return None

    else:
        last_name = raw_input("Enter last name: ")
        nick_name = raw_input("Enter nickname: ")
        address = raw_input("Enter address: ")
        number = raw_input("Enter phone number: ")        

        return {
            'nick':nick_name,
            'firstname':first_name,
            'lastname':last_name,
            'address':address,
            'number':number
        }


MyDict['Johnny'] = GetDetail()
print MyDict
```

Sample Input and Output:

Enter last name: Higazi

Enter nickname: tameritoke

Enter address: MyHomeStreet

Enter phone number: 000-1999

{'Johnny': {'nick': 'tameritoke', 'address': 'MyHomeStreet', 'number': '000-1999', 'firstname': 'Tamer', 'lastname': 'Higazi'}}